# How to move my GnuPG home directory from Ubuntu to Mac?

Tags: ubuntu, osx, gpg

I've used `gpg2` to generate some keys on my Ubuntu 16.04 server. Now I have to move the machine. I need to transfer all generated keys to a Mac. I think I just have to copy the `~/.gnupg` files.

But where do I have to store it to get them called via `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG mr@robot.sh`? Same place?

And how do I install `gpg2` on my Mac? `homebrew gpg2` is not existing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the machine that initially has the keys (the Ubuntu machine):

Export the public keys:

```
gpg --export --armor --output=key_public.asc
```

Export the private keys:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys --armor --output=key_secret.asc
```

Copy the exported files to the second machine (the Mac).

Import the keys:

```
gpg --import --armor key_public.asc
```

and

```
gpg --import --armor key_secret.asc
```

---

The above commands will export all the keys in your keyring. If you just want a specific key/s, you need to specify it/them by uid.

Comment: This only copies keys and signatures, but omits trust (if you set up any). You might especially have to issue ultimate trust to your own secret key.

Comment: I did exact this, but I just get the public key imported. I thought using `--export` will export both keys...

Comment: My memory failed me. Upon testing, `--export` only exports public keys. I've updated the answer with corrected info.

Answer (score 2):

Just put them again to `~/.gnupg`, but make sure to fix any user ID issues afterwards: `chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.gnupg`. If you still have issues afterwards, make sure you run GnuPG under the expected user and thus the GnuPG is searching in the right GnuPG home directory. `gpg --version` will also print the home directory in use.

The [`gnupg` homebrew package](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gnupg.rb) installs GnuPG 2.2 at the time writing this post. What you used to execute as `gpg2` is now `gpg`, also Ubuntu and other Linux distributions switched to releases of GnuPG 2.x as default for `gpg` by now. Some time ago, there was a dedicated `gnupg2` package in homebrew, but this is now merged into `gnupg`.